# How do I confirm (online) what the current supported version of MySQL for RHEL 5.6?

Tags: mysql, redhat

without doing a yum update.
We would like to know if we are running the latest version of MySQL.

Comment: Erik, nice seeing you again :) I mentioned before this user is bugged and won't let me register.  I complete the registration and it won't let me use this 'anonymous' user again logging me into a new user.  Then 3 weeks later (without even looking), my posted question was posted as the original bugged user.  If u can help that would be great!

Comment: Also I remember to upvote and "find answer helpful" as much as I can with my 'registered user'.

Comment: John, like I said last time, post a question over in meta.serverfault.com, and one of the mods can help you get your account sorted out.

Comment: Are you talking about the community version or the enterprise version?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the command `yum info mysql-server` to get this information. Here is an example of a MySQL install that could be upgraded:

```
# yum info mysql-server
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, rhnplugin, security
Installed Packages
Name       : mysql-server
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 5.0.77
Release    : 4.el5_5.5
Size       : 22 M
Repo       : installed
Summary    : The MySQL server and related files.
URL        : http://www.mysql.com
License    : GPLv2 with exceptions
Description: MySQL is a multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database server. MySQL is a
           : client/server implementation consisting of a server daemon (mysqld)
           : and many different client programs and libraries. This package contains
           : the MySQL server and some accompanying files and directories.

Available Packages
Name       : mysql-server
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 5.0.95
Release    : 1.el5_7.1
Size       : 9.9 M
Repo       : rhel-x86_64-server-5
Summary    : The MySQL server and related files
License    : GPLv2 with exceptions
Description: MySQL is a multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database server. MySQL is a
           : client/server implementation consisting of a server daemon (mysqld)
           : and many different client programs and libraries. This package contains
           : the MySQL server and some accompanying files and directories.
```

You could use `yum check-update` if you like, but that will list *all* updates for your system; here's a little bit of an example:

```
# yum check-update
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, rhnplugin, security
Skipping security plugin, no data

Deployment_Guide-en-US.noarch                                             5.8-1.el5                                                            rhel-x86_64-server-5
NetworkManager.i386                                                       1:0.7.0-13.el5                                                       rhel-x86_64-server-5
NetworkManager.x86_64                                                     1:0.7.0-13.el5                                                       rhel-x86_64-server-5
NetworkManager-glib.i386                                                  1:0.7.0-13.el5                                                       rhel-x86_64-server-5
NetworkManager-glib.x86_64                                                1:0.7.0-13.el5                                                       rhel-x86_64-server-5
PyXML.x86_64                                                              0.8.4-6.el5                                                          rhel-x86_64-server-5
SysVinit.x86_64                                                           2.86-17.el5                                                          rhel-x86_64-server-5
acl.x86_64                                                                2.2.39-8.el5                                                         rhel-x86_64-server-5
acpid.x86_64                                                              1.0.4-12.el5                                                         rhel-x86_64-server-5
alsa-utils.x86_64                                                         1.0.17-6.el5
```

I'd recommend using `yum info` instead.

Comment: Neither of the command recommended are `yum update`: One is `yum info` and one is `yum check-update`.

Answer (score 1):

run the command

```
yum check-update
```

or check rhn.redhat.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

From what I see there, 5.6 has not passed GA yet

EDIT: Just caught on what you really meant by the question. In this case, I suggest you just browse the RHEL repository and search for the mysql-server package. The version should be there.

Alternatively, you could browse the CentOS repository for the same version, since it is based on RHEL, the versions are exactly the same.

Comment: This is not the current supported MySQL version for RHEL, but is the current stable version of MySQL from Oracle. These are _not_ the same thing.

Comment: Ohhhhh I see what he means, sorry.